# Grails design for domain class initialization from static data

Tags: grails, dns, bootstrapping

I have some data, stateNames, to instantiate an instance of the object Country.  Right now, I will only have one Country but stateNames for each country should be different.  What is the best way to instantiate the instance of Country with my data?  I am new to grails and would appreciate any "best practices" or common designs.

One solution I can think of is to use BootStrap to save the unitedStates instance of Country to the database.  What are the cons of this approach?

Another solution would be to save the data in a file (in xml?) under web-app folder.  If I did this approach, should the unitedStates instance of Country be instantiated by a controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A project should aim to run in development mode without any setup after checking out the code.  With this in mind, `BootStrap.groovy` is a good place to initialize the database with a minimal data set, such as user accounts or static data like country names.

A common pattern is to check for some known instance -- like an admin user account -- and insert the minimal data set if it is absent.  For example:

```
class BootStrap {

    def init = { servletContext ->
        def admin = User.findByUsername('admin')
        if (!admin) {
            // initialize the database by inserting a minimal data set
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Great, that's what I've got.

Answer (score 0):

write a service accepting input and persisting into DB , and call it from anywhere, be it bootstrap or controller according to your requirement.Boot strap is good way for heavy lifting.

Comment: What do you mean by the service "persisting into DB?"

Comment: i was saying about initialization of static data as ataylor suggested